# Can I renew the 4-year hosting plan at Hostinger after it expired?

Tags: hosting, web-hosting

I'm about to build a website for personal use and I found Hostinger to be very cheap, the plan I choose is $2.15 a month for 48 months, but I haven't been able to determine if that plan can be renewed after those initial 4 years is done. What I mean is, after 4 years, can I buy another 4 year plan for $2.15/month? Or do I have to pay the full price (~$11/month) after the initial 4 years is done.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The renewal prices are a bit higher than the first one, but it's not the full price. There are some discounts for the renewals too but the initial cost is lower. I have Premium account with them and the renewal for 4 more years now is 3.49$/month.
Remember that the prices still can change in 4 years because of the economical changes. However, these renewal prices here are really not bad.

Comment: BTW, right now they have another discount - found their coupon SUMMER19, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can renew it after specified time and meanwhile you can choose to opt for other vendors hosting plan, if found to be cheaper then you current plan. But yes you can renew the existing one after 4 years.